# what am i doing wrong in this high order function with arrays? JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

So, I'm trying to learn about high order functions and am doing exercises and whatnot. I need the result to be a return of the elements of the original array input that are less than 6 characters in length. But I think I screwed up the syntax. Not sure how I can do this with a higher order function. Help?

```js
var courses = [calculus,cs17,litr0100,engn];

reduce(function() {
    courses.filter(courses => courses.length > 6);
    return courses;
})
```

Comment: `filter` does not mutate the original object - return the result of `.filter` instead

Comment: There's also no freestanding `reduce` function by default in JavaScript.

Comment: What's the point of calling `reduce` with a function that ignores its arguments? In fact, what's the point of calling `reduce` at all if all you want is the result of `filter`?

Comment: reduce is just the name of the function that I made; I didn't know that it was taken by JS. I'll change it

Comment: @Jabrah What does your function do? It seems odd that it takes as its only argument a 0-arity function with no side-effects.

Comment: @sepp2k The goal is to only return elements of the original array that are less than 6 characters in length. The only reason I did it this way is because I'm trying to learn about higher order functions.

Comment: I meant what does your `reduce` function do - not the anonymous function. Is it just `function reduce(f) { return f(); }` or what?

Answer (score 1):

What am I doing wrong?

```
var courses = [calculus,cs17,litr0100,engn];
//             ^ unless these are variables this will fail
//  use let or const

reduce(function() {
// javascript does not know a reduce function
// the reducer (lambda) function has no parameters
    courses.filter(courses => courses.length > 6);
//                 ^ should be 'course' or something else then 'courses' 
//  filtering with the right syntax would've been sufficient
    return courses;
})
```

so

```js
const courses = "calculus,cs17,litr0100,engn".split(",");
const coursesFiltered = courses.filter(course => course.length > 6);
//                    ^ assign the filtered array to a different array  
//                      Array.filter doesn't mutate (change) the original
console.log(courses);
console.log(coursesFiltered);
```

Start studying: [**Array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [**Array.reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [**Array.filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)